# algorithm for drawing dendrogram stepwise from clustered objects in a tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I want to draw a dendrogram from objects which I have already clustered and saved in a (leave)tree. My Cluster object in Java can be represented by these pictures. Each leaves contains an object and each node contains the distance between its children.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nktv.png]

Now, I want to draw a dendrogram stepwise, so first object 1 and 2 should be drawn, then object 3 should be added to those. Then 5 and 6 together etc.. to the end where everything is connected. I already have all the tools to draw this easily, but I cannot find an efficient way in walking through the tree correctly.

This should be the result so far in the example (EDIT: There's a mistake, the distance from 5 to 6 now looks smaller than the distance from 3 to 1&2, but that isn't the case in my example!):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gecAF.png]

Does anyone have some tips for this recursive algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

you're rendering depth first - you may find you need to keep track of depth to get the layout to work right - also note you have to draw non-terminal notes as well ("*" gets drawn before 3)

basically

```
draw(node)
{
   if(hasleft) draw(left)
   if(hasright) draw(right)
   drawme()
}
```

this does assume a binary tree, but that is what you've drawn - and this is going to get a lot more complicated because of layout issues - you really want to consider drawing breadth first from the top down, it makes layout a lot less painful

Comment: For the outlining part, I think starting from the bottom is easier (I know I have to start next to the labels in the added picture). The tree is not entirely a binary search tree, i.e. the two trees could again be clustered to one tree, then it isn't anymore I think?

Comment: ah, changing the layout will make things easier but not perfect - however it's reasonably straightforward if you never intend on labeling anything but terminal nodes - but the first layout is far nicer - you are correct that the second diagram is not a binary tree, as the root element has 4 children - however note that for any parent line, you need to know the total # of children in order to figure the vertical offset of the parent lint

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean this, but the first picture is not a layout, it's just a visual representation with Paint of my Tree Class in Java with some data in it, to make it clear what my clustered object is like.